infinite recursion while evaluating 'inputs'
Overview
I'm trying to install the 1password shell plugins via Nix in home-manager on macOS. However I keep getting the following error:
...
… while calling anonymous lambda

         at /nix/store/c9p7p3mgi0wvymm2fc3knx0z4nnk5sb1-source/lib/modules.nix:518:35:

          517|       context = name: ''while evaluating the module argument `${name}' in "${key}":'';
          518|       extraArgs = mapAttrs (name: _:
             |                                   ^
          519|         addErrorContext (context name)

       … while evaluating the module argument `inputs' in "/nix/store/fkc2vkp8girdrhp644dfcsvjwjgkn1z4-source/home/1password":

       error: infinite recursion encountered

       at /nix/store/c9p7p3mgi0wvymm2fc3knx0z4nnk5sb1-source/lib/modules.nix:520:28:

          519|         addErrorContext (context name)
          520|           (args.${name} or config._module.args.${name})
             |                            ^
          521|       ) (functionArgs f);

Setup
I am going through the 1password docs to install the shell plugins with Nix. It essentially involves adding a new input and then importing that input (see #Files) below).
Debug
I've isolated the root cause to be somewhere around the import statement. If I comment out the import in home/1password/default.nix, I can switch successfully. However as soon as I add in that one line, I get the above error.
I've looked on SourceGraph for other installations of the shell plugins in Nix, but I haven't found anything that looks substantially different than my setup and works when I apply the change.
Files
# flake.nix
  inputs = {
    nixpkgs.url = "github:NixOS/nixpkgs/nixpkgs-unstable";
    nix-darwin = {
      url = "github:LnL7/nix-darwin";
      inputs.nixpkgs.follows = "nixpkgs";
    };
    home-manager = {
      url = "github:nix-community/home-manager";
      inputs.nixpkgs.follows = "nixpkgs";
    };
    _1password-shell-plugins = {
      url = "github:1Password/shell-plugins";
      inputs.nixpkgs.follows = "nixpkgs";
    };
  };

# home/1password/default.nix

{ inputs, pkgs, ... }:
{
  imports = [ inputs._1password-shell-plugins.hmModules.default ];
}


Where is your flake output conf?
